# Edit multiple custom post types while saving a new or edited post

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

I have a custom post type with some custom fields in it.

Now what i want to do is when i save a new OR edit an existing post in that post type, is to change custom fields from all the other posts of that custom post type.

I'm familiar with the update_post_meta, but i can't figure out on how to get the post ID's of all the other posts to update them all.

Comment: Allready figured it out!

Just by using the normal WP_Query function!

Here's my snippet:

// here i set a var for the post id that i actualy edited so that later on i can make sure the edited post is not being changed again
$postedid = $post->ID;

$getmyposts = new WP_Query('post_type=mycustomposttype&posts_per_page=-1');
 while ( $getmyposts->have_posts() ) : $getmyposts->the_post();
//check if it is the post i just edited, otherwise change it 
if ( $post->ID == $postedid ) { }
 else {
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "metatermname", yourvalue); 
 }
 endwhile;

Answer (score 2):

here is how i would do that:

```
add_action('save_post','update_all_meta');

function update_all_meta($post_id){
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return;
    //check for post type
    if ( $post->post_type != "YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE" ) 
        return;
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;
    $args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TYPE',
        'post__not_in' => (array)$post->ID //skip current post
        );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    //loop over all custom posts and update the meta
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post); 
        update_post_meta($post->ID,'meta_key',$meta_value);
    }
    $post = $tmp_post;
}
```

but if the stored data is the same maybe use options api so you only update it one and you can use it for all posts.